# loop dataframe based on condition find first corresponding row in another column, then skip next set find first corresponding row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following df
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA6RU.png)

Some emails are invalid, and the only way that I can tell is that for the same Account Name if there're any odd one(s) out, e.g. no@nonsense.com under Customer A

I have attempted to compare Account Names and Emails, but quite stuck on how to loop through each account and only pick out the odd ones out

Code-

```
df['Account_Name-next'] = df['Account_Name'].shift(-1)
df['Email-next'] = df['Email'].shift(-1)

df['Account_Name_equ'] = df['Account_Name-next'] == df['Account_Name']
df['Email-equ'] = df['Email-next'] == df['Email']

for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.Account_Name_equ == True:
        continue
    print(df['Email'][0])
    if row.Account_Name_equ == False:
        break
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? try df.head().to_dict()

Comment: hi @yolao_21, here's a sample of the https://file.io/fmghKogo8FQX
what would df.head().to_dict() achieve?

Comment: In order for other users to be able to reproduce the situation presented, it is important to provide some data. Please provide us with some data.